# HTML string to formatted text in Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift

Hello I have a string that I want to write to a text document in Swift. Because the text document has line breaks, however, the string seems to be in HTML format.
Here is what I want to do:

```
    //Covert str1 to str2
    var str1 = "1<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>"
    var str2 = "1        
                2
                3
                4" //Text document will have text that looks like this (With line breaks)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with NSAttributedString:

```
let htmlString = "1<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>"
NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)!,
options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
documentAttributes: nil,
error: nil);
```

this will produce:

```
"1\n2\n3\n4\n"
```

Comment: If this is always NSAttributedString, how do  write that to a text file?

Comment: NSAttributedString has property `string`

Comment: from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSAttributedString/string): `Attachment characters are not removed from the value of this property`

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0: You can pop this directly into Xcode's playground to check it out.

```
let htmlString = "1<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>"
func getHtmlFormat(fromString htmlString: String) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let htmlData = htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode) else
    {
        print("Could not get htmlData")
        return nil
    }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
textView.attributedText = getHtmlFormat(fromString: htmlString)
```